# android setting speech to text for two edit texts

Tags: java, android

I have created two edit texts. And i created two buttons. By clicking on a button, it will ask for user to speak and it will convert the speech to text and it will 
 be displayed in the edit text.

I have called the voice to text function two times. One for first edit text and other for second edit text. But it displaying the error.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
private void promptSpeechInput1() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Receiving speech input
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                txtSpeechInput1.setText(result.get(0));

            }
            break;
        }

    }
}



//////////////


private void promptSpeechInput2() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Receiving speech input
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                txtSpeechInput2.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

And the error shows on the line:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
```

Comment: please share your error log

Comment: error:method onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) is already defined in class MainActivity
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redefining the onActivityResult method. Use only one instance for your purpose

```
/**
 * Receiving speech input and output
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtSpeechInput1.setText(result.get(0));

        }
        break;
     }
     case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_OUTPUT: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtSpeechInput2.setText(result.get(0));
        }
        break;

    }



   }
}
```

and modify this in your promptSpeechInput2 method. Use different request code i.e. not REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT else use REQ_CODE_SPEECH_OUTPUT with different value

```
try {
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_OUTPUT);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: please let me know your mail id. So that I can ask any doubts to you.@Shriyansh Gautam